# Confusing wording on overloading in 8.4.9 of Java SE 7 Specifications

Tags: java, overloading

Here, I am quoting the first line in 8.4.9 of Java SE 7 Specifications:

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.

So, anything not qualified to be override-equivalent is said to be overloaded.

But the two methods in the example below are neither override-equivalent nor can be considered valid for overloading.

```
public String my_method(int x) {.....} 
public int my_method(int x) {.....}
```

**Invalid for overriding** because the return type of one is not a subclass of the return of the other.

**Invalid for overloading** because different return types alone are not sufficient for two methods to be considered overloaded.

Any comments on 8.4.9? Perhaps I am missing something in my perception.

Comment: What does the text say for that part in Java 8?

Comment: @Kayaman: Identical wording in SE 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you are missing is that the return type of a method is not part of its signature.

The definition of override-equivalent in 8.4.2 says:

> "Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types."

Note that there is no mention of return types in the definition.

Then it says:

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or [...]
>
> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.

So two methods that the same names and the same argument types, but different result types ARE override-equivalent.

Finally 8.4.2 says:

> "It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class."

so your example code is illegal if the methods are in the same class.

On the other hand, if one is in a subclass of the class containing the other, then according to the rules in 8.4.5, neither method is not return-type-substitutable with the other ... so that would also be a compilation error.

Comment: If I place the former one in a base class and the latter in a derived class, then what happens? There are some restrictions on overriding/overridden methods. The return type of the method in the derived class has to be a subclass (if not the same) of the return type of the method in the base class. So, considering this restriction, can we call the methods override-equivalent?

Comment: 1)  You get a compilation error because the two methods are not return-type-substitutable.  2)  No you can't.  The definition of override-equivalent says you can't.  (Your intuition is incorrect ... the restrictions on overriding methods with different return types come from the "return-type-substitutable" rule.  That doesn't alter the definition of override-equivalence.)

Answer (score 2):

The following information from two other sections resolves your concern:

[8.4.2 Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

> It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.

[8.4.5 Method Return Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)

> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2, if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> - If R1 is void then R2 is void.
> - If R1 is a primitive type, then R2 is identical to R1.
> - If R1 is a reference type then:
>
>   - R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), or
>   - R1 = |R2|

Answer (score 0):

According to [8.4.2. Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) the return type is **not** part of the signature. So the methods in your question are not overloads, but they are overrides. This override is not compatible due to an incompatible change to the method result, as specified in [8.4.5. Method Result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5):

> Return types may vary among methods that override each other if the return types are reference types. The notion of return-type-substitutability supports *covariant returns*, that is, the specialization of the return type to a subtype.
>
> A method declaration `d1` with return type `R1` is *return-type-substitutable* for another method `d2` with return type `R2` iff any of the following is true:
>
> - If `R1` is `void` then `R2` is `void`.
> - If `R1` is a primitive type then `R2` is identical to `R1`.
> - If `R1` is a reference type then one of the following is true:
>
>   - `R1`, adapted to the type parameters of `d2` ([§8.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)), is a subtype of `R2`.
>   - `R1` can be converted to a subtype of `R2` by unchecked conversion ([§5.1.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)).
>   - `d1` does not have the same signature as `d2` ([§8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)), and `R1 = |R2|`.

This is also specified in [8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> If a method declaration `d1` with return type `R1` overrides or hides the declaration of another method `d2` with return type `R2`, then `d1` must be return-type-substitutable ([§8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)) for `d2`, or a compile-time error occurs.